# vb.net: test if a com dll is registered at runtime

Tags: vb.net, dll, com

How can I check at runtime whether a dll has registered correctly?  Currently trying the following, but it never finds the dll even though it is registered with `regsvr32`.  Does the Assembly class only work for system assemblies, and if so, what do I use for my own ones?

```
    'check com dll connection for diagnostics
    Try
        Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("mycomdll.mycomclass")
        DebugText.AppendText("DLL registered" + vbNewLine)
    Catch ex As Exception
        DebugText.AppendText("DLL test failed" + vbNewLine)
        DebugText.AppendText(ex.ToString() + vbNewLine)
    End Try
```

Comment: That cannot work, the *unmanaged* server is normally found by COM using the registry.  Something you only approximate, but never can faithfully reproduce with the many convoluted rules that govern  COM server hosting, isolation, redirection and manifest overrides.  The simple approach is to just create the COM server and catch the exception when it isn't available.

Comment: Sounds logical.  How do I load the unmanaged server at runtime?  I've only found out how to do this by adding a project reference, which complains at compile time if the server is not present.

Comment: As I said, by creating an object.  COM servers are loaded on demand.

Comment: I see, `CreateObject()` would be what I want then.  I didn't know about that function having got by without it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    'check com dll connection for diagnostics
    Try
        Dim test As Object = CreateObject("mycomdll.mycomclass")
        test.mymethod(0)
        DebugText.AppendText("COM DLL registered" + vbNewLine)
    Catch ex As Exception
        DebugText.AppendText("COM test failed" + vbNewLine)
        DebugText.AppendText(ex.ToString() + vbNewLine + vbNewLine)
    End Try
```